# Expression builder for GroupBy Lamda for each property

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I want to populate the itemsource of a ComboBox with items from my List, depending on which property from T is selected.

The statement should be like:
foreach property which is a string,
  select the values of the property, make distinct.

```
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CreateSuggestionsLists<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "left");
        foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            var callExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExp, pi);
            var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(callExpr) ;
            // From here on it goes wrong!!!
            var comleteExpr = lambdaExpr as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
            var compiledExpr = comleteExpr.Compile();

            var res = data.Select(compiledExpr).Distinct().ToList();
            // add to results ...
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The problem seems to be the casting from the lambda expression to prepare for compilation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Rather than cast, you should use `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callExpr, paramExp)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide `paramExp` to lambda. Secondly there is generic version of `Lamda` method which is just easier to use. Finally, you don't need to compile expression when you use `IQueryable`. You created `queryableData` variable and didn't use it.

Here is code:

```
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CreateSuggestionsLists<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "left");
        foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            var callExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExp, pi);
            var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callExpr, paramExp);

            var res = queryableData.Select(lambdaExpr).Distinct().ToList();
            // add to results ...
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check if the casting result is not null :

```
          public Dictionary<string, List<string>> CreateSuggestionsLists<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "left");

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            MemberExpression callExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExp, pi);
            LambdaExpression lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(callExpr);
            // From here on it goes wrong!!!
            if (!(lambdaExpr is Expression<Func<T, bool>> comleteExpr)) continue;

            Func<T, bool> compiledExpr =  comleteExpr.Compile();

            List<bool> res = data.Select(compiledExpr).Distinct().ToList();

            // add to results ...
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shehab, thanks for your suggestion.Unfortunately the cast is null for all properties. The lambdaexpression is {() => f.X}, but the cast is always null.

Comment: Ok let's begin again can you clarify what you're expecting from this method because the lambdaExpr is Expressions<Func<string>>